# Password policy using pam_cracklib is not enforced for root in gui

Tags: linux, security, passwords

I'm on Red Hat 6.6 now, trying to enforce password policy for root user. My /etc/pam.d/system-auth file contains following lines:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprintd.so
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=5 unlock_time=900
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_tally2.so
account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type= ucredit=-1 lcredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1 maxrepeat=3 \
                                          reject_username enforce_for_root
password    sufficient    /lib64/security/pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok remember=5 use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

It works for passwd command, when I'm trying to change password to simple (like '123'), it is not accepting password.

But when I'm trying to change it through GUI (gnome2, system-config-users utility) it only throws warnings about bad password complexity and I can apply weak password anyway.

How can I deny setting weak passwords through GUI?

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded source code of system-config-users and it seems that there's no such possibility(it always suggest to continue even if pam fails)